# C printing char array gets messed up when saving a char within an array of chars

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a function that basically prints out an array of characters. It's reading a data file where each line has the following structure:

**.txt file to read:**

```
a   30
```

the space in-between is a tab. So I know each line has 3 characters (not counting a null terminator or newline character). Thus, I use that knowledge to say hey, when I get to array[2] in the loop, then start keeping track of that integer and add it to a buffer.

My issue is within the `printCharArray(char *arr)` function.

**C Program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int printCharArray(char *arr);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    FILE * filePointer;
    filePointer = fopen("test1.txt", "r");
    char singleLine[32];

    // gets the line of file, and sends it to the print function i made
    while(fgets(singleLine, 32, filePointer) != NULL){
        printCharArray(singleLine);
    }

    fclose(filePointer);
    return 0;
}

int printCharArray(char *arr){
    int length = 5;
    printf("\n");

    int i = 0;
    char buffer[16];

    // loops until it hits the end of a line
    while(arr[i] != '\n') {
        // prints each character, separated by commas
        printf("%c, ", arr[i]);


        // this is to start storing the integer chars at the end of the line
        if(i > 1){
            size_t len = strlen(buffer);
            buffer[len++] = arr[i];
            buffer[len] = '\0';
        }

         // get the first item in the line, aka i (insert) or d (delete)
         // THIS IS WHAT BREAKS THE PROGRAM
        if(i == 0){
            char aORb = arr[0];
        }

        i++;

    }
    printf("string = %s \n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is the `if (i == 0)` part of the `printCharArray()` function. When that part is deleted, the output works currectly:

```
string = 30
```

But when I put the `if (i == 0)` statement, I get `string = p(?10`. How is it possible that simply saving one of the chars in a variable during the loop could mess it up?

Comment: `char buffer[16];` --> `char buffer[16] = "";`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that worked, but what does that mean? Why did that cause a problem?

Comment: It is not possible to properly use `strlen` for an uninitialized array of `char`.

Comment: @JamesMitchell - the second part of that is basic array initialization. When you initialize the first element in an array (or member of a struct) all remaining elements are set to zero. So `char buffer[16] = "";` sets `buffer[0] = '\0';` (because `""` is the *empty-string* which contains only a nul-terminating char, which is `char '\0'` -- or just `'0'`). The rest of the elements are set to zero. You could also do `char buffer[16] = {0};` which is equivalent.

Comment: "you know it has 3?" What, it has 4 there! Tab is a character too.